# How to use external css variables in styled-components?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have CSS variables in separate file and I want to use them inside styled-components. It is not working as expected. Any suggestions ?

**./vars.css**

```
:root {
    --yellow-fs: yellow;
}
```

**./Button.styled.tsx**

```
import './vars.css';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const StyledButton = styled.button`
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--yellow-fs);
`
```

Comment: This code is already working. Can you check the demo https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-demo-lic3v?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thanks for responding. But it is not working in my project.

Comment: Can you share your code with problem in codesanbox?

Comment: Above code almost the same code. What do you think postcss config could be reason ?

Comment: I wouldn't know until I see the code.

Comment: Ok I found solution. Reason for this problem was postcss config in webpack. I removed it and everything is working fine.
Summary: No need to install any package to use external css in styled-components.